# TRS Mic works on phone but not computer

Tags: audio, microphone, 3.5mm

I got a `Remax 200HB` headphone which has a built-in mic. It is a Bluetooth device, however, it can also be used using a wire. The package has a TRS jack in it. I also have a wired headphone with TRRS jack. Here is how my devices are behaving:

1. Phone and Bluetooth - Mic works
2. Phone and TRRS - Mic works
3. Phone and TRS - Mic works (see edit)
4. Computer and TRRS - Mic works
5. Computer and TRS - Mic **does not** work

Can you please explain why the last case does not work? Also, what can be a solution to make it work?

**Edit**
Rechecked the case of "Phone and TRS" ss per suggestion from @Spiff. Turns out it works using the built-in mic of the phone. The headphone's mic does not work. It makes sense now.

So now the question comes down to: **should I use a TRS female TRRS male converted? Or a TRRS male TRRS male cable should work?**

Comment: You need an adaptor. See - https://superuser.com/a/1568512/347380

Comment: Can you re-test #3 "Phone and TRS" with your phone's Bluetooth radio completely disabled? The only way this makes sense to me is if #3 was still secretly using Bluetooth. Or maybe if your phone's built-in mic was picking up your speech…?

Comment: @Spiff, what you guessed is right, please check the edit.

Comment: This is one of those occasions I'd go to an actual shop & ask the staff [take all your stuff with you]. There are so many variants of the TRRS pinout that guesswork is unlikely to hit the right combination first time.