# Can a audio splitter work to join 2 male 3.5mm from the same DAC to one output?

Tags: audio, splitter, analog

The problem arose due to the nature of the audio meant for headphones with two inputs, left and the right one. But my headphone only has a single input. This, instead of sending the DAC back I’d like to use it.

Comment: Cheap headphone jack splitter 3.5 mm.

Comment: You can bridge mono by connecting L&R together. This is probably a DIY soldering job, as it's not something many people need. We need to know the pinout of your existing devices & cables to suggest a specific circuit. A generic 'splitter' will not work. See https://superuser.com/a/1568512/347380 for some related info (but this is not the specific fix for your instance, it just describes various pinouts).

Comment: even if the 2 audio sources are the same device? can't I plug them together?

Comment: We can't see what the device is, nor the headphones, nor do we have enough information to guess from. Please add details to your question.

Comment: the device is https://www.amazon.com/beyerdynamic-Universal-High-End-Headphone-Amplifier/dp/B077XDZGQP and the Headphone from Beyerdynamic has only one side for 3.5mm. Headphones: https://www.beyerdynamic.de/mmx-300.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAnvj9BRA4EiwAuUMDfwmrAxOXi0-N5BSCvfvMWVESp80ShdGmzUqkqC-uq-C24j6gCM8hcxoCY3cQAvD_BwE

Comment: You bought a DAC for output only (for **headphones**) & you're trying to connect a **headset** with a built-in microphone. Unless you want to ignore the microphone entirely, you need a different DAC.

Comment: yes the microphone can be ignored as i don't use it. I was only worried if my equipment would be damaged if i connect them together.

Comment: Take them to a hi-fi or phone shop & ask them which cable you need. They might have one. I don't have the time or energy to look up the pinouts for both of them.

Comment: Well right now i can't do that but thank you for your help anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is to use mono to the stereo adapter, the ones you used in Aircraft with two 3.5mm male to one 3.5mm female and using 2 another female to female adapters like here:https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41CGgaiNpaL._SX180_.jpg did the trick for me.

Important Note: This is only safe if both the L and R channels come from the same device(In my case a DAC).