# External microphone not working

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

There are several posts about an external microphone not working, but none of them is an exact match.

I am trying to connect an external microphone (Bietrun UHF Wireless) to HP EliteBook 840 G8 with Windows 10 Pro (build 19044). The device manager says that the Realtek Audio input driver is working properly. However, the test says that the microphone is not connected.

The microphone works just fine on another laptop (from Dell). The 3.5mm jack works with headphones. I don't have another mic to try.

I tried reinstalling the driver without a result. The BIOS test does not recognize the mic either.

I called HP support. They said that, since the 3.5mm jack works with headphones, it's not a hardware problem.

What steps can I check to fix this?

**Another detail**: When the Realtek driver is not installed and I put in the mic, it sometimes adds the Realtek driver to the output devices, i.e. it is sure the mic is headphones. Then I manually add Realtek to input devices (tried also disabling it in the output devices), but the mic is still not working.

Comment: Is it a standalone Mic with a 2 or 3 pole plug? This may or may not be relevant, but some HP Laptops have Stereo headphone/microphone combo port. The port works in such a way that it rejects standalone Mic device. It only understands the combo of Headphone + Mic system i.e. a 4 pole plug that integrates Headphone & Mic together. Yet 3 pole only headphone plug alone works fine there.

Comment: Continued...  https://support.hp.com/in-en/product/hp-elitebook-840-g8-notebook-pc/38216725/manuals   http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06719950.pdf   See page 14  https://i.imgur.com/fRiuO2A.png

Comment: @patkim The laptop has only one 3.5mm jack, so it's both input and output. It was the same in my Dell Precision 5520, but when I inserted the mic, it asked whether it's headphones or a mic. If there is something else that I need to check about poles (sorry, I don't know what those are), please let me know how I can check it to provide the information.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the driver for the mic input and installing the latest one from the HP driver page?

Comment: https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-840-g8-notebook-pc/38216725

Comment: No sadly it's not temporary. This has always been a problem with HP Driver page for me also. If you have any popup blockers or adblock extensions you'll want to exclude the site from it being blocked. After that it should hopefully behave.

Comment: @Mastaxx Yes, it worked from another browser... I uninstalled the RealTek drivers. After downloading the audio driver  from the HP site and running the provided installer, the driver is still not appearing in the device manager... As soon as I plugged in the mic, all the drivers got back just like they were previously and the mic is not working...

Comment: I will check [this](https://superuser.com/a/1693045/624486) claim, although it seems strange  given that the mic worked with my Dell laptop...

Comment: I have HP laptop with combo port. My standalone 3 pole pin Mic does not work when plugged in there, but when I connect my splitter (4 pole) and connect Mic to the Mic end on the splitter, it's properly detected and works.