# Is it possible to use a microphone that is plugged into the headphone jack of a Lenovo X230?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, microphone, headphone-jack

Usually, I have a doc. station, but currently I'm abroad and forgot it. The day after tomorrow I have a very important meeting, but can't connect my microphone.

I tried to plugging it into a headphone jack, but Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS recognizes it as a headphone, not a microphone.

Is it possible to use a microphone that is plugged into the headphone jack of a Lenovo X230?

Comment: What connector does the microphone have? If you look through [this Quora article](https://www.quora.com/I-want-to-connect-a-3-5-mm-TRRS-external-mic-to-my-laptop-but-it-has-3-5mm-TRS-audio-input-what-should-I-do), you can see illustrations of TS, TRS, and TRRS plugs - which one is yours?

Comment: Also, does the laptop's built-in microphone give acceptable sound quality? And are you somewhere that you could buy, for example, a USB headset from a shop?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry for troubling, I've already found out in the manual that it does support out line, but it doesn't support conventional microphone. The built-in microphone isn't kind of best, but if I am close enough to the laptop, it can be acceptable. What should I do with topic? Delete it?

Comment: It is possible to get adapters to go from some microphone plugs to some laptop sockets, so if you are able to purchase an adapter from a local electronics shop, that might be a good option - I suggest that you leave your question here for a few more hours in case someone else has had the same problem with that model of laptop on Ubuntu. You are of course free to delete your question if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have detailed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1693045/714576), using only a Mic will never work. If this is a combined jack with four pins, you could get a audio splitter such as [this random example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09VXVV3YL), but this means you'll need to connect a headphone too, otherwise the setup won't work.

Your best chance is to get a USB audio adapter with separate mic and headphone jack, such as [this random example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N905VOY) which will allow you to connect only the mic.

You should be able to get any of these quite easily in a local electronics shops, for not too much money.